# delaying an operation for on-boarding

Tags: objective-c, events, uibutton

I have a button on a UIView. 
the onclick method opens another view. 
For the on boarding experience the first time the user clicks on that button I want to show him an explanation screen only when the user closes the explanation screen the actual button operation should fire

any ideas how can I delay the operation?

Comment: Can you post some code? Do you want to delay it using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this with no code but you can use NSUserDefaults to detect the first time:

```
 //Show the screen on the first load only
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(![defaults objectForKey:@"firstLoad"]){
        NSNumber *firstLoad = @YES;
        [defaults setObject:firstLoad forKey:@"firstLoad"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        //Put your code here to show the message, how do you do this? UIAlertView?


    }

    else{

        //just go to the first screen


    }
```

Here is the dictionary key doesn't exist we can pop a message maybe use UIAlertView or something, you will have to write the code for the delegate so when OK is tapped you push to your next view controller. You can see if the key already exists we know not to show the message and you can go directly to the next screen.